# Determine how many times a specific OS has been booted

Tags: grub2

Maybe my question is a bit silly to ask, but are there any way to count how many times a specific item was selected from GRUB2.

I will have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 installed and I would like to make a chart and statistics about my OS usage. I only need the two numbers how many times I started each.

I can use a notebook for that, but if there is a way to automatize a task, why not? :)

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about Windows, but the last couple of times you rebooted Ubuntu can be found with `last | grep reboot` and `last -f /var/log/wtmp.1 | grep reboot`. Does that help?

Comment: @Jos It's not a complete solution for my problem, but thanks, I will try it anyways. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time Ubuntu boots, it logs the fact in `/var/log/kern.log`. On my system, I see:

```
Dec  2 10:00:11 squid kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec  2 10:00:11 squid kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec  2 10:00:11 squid kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Dec  2 10:00:11 squid kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.13.0-71-generic (buildd@lgw01-09) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 1 02:34:22 UTC 2015 (Ubuntu 3.13.0-71.114-generic 3.13.11-ckt29)
Dec  2 10:00:11 squid kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.13.0-71-generic root=UUID=88dc0c09-632f-4265-8933-a967351220ae ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

`Dec  2 10:00:11` is When, `squid` is my hostname, `kernel:` is who issued the message, `[    0.000000]` is time since boot(!), and the rest is the message. You could do:

```
zgrep 'Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=' /var/log/kern.log*
```

to see them all, or:

```
zgrep 'Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=' /var/log/kern.log* | wc -l
```

to count reboots.